# Resources on parsing expressions

Tags: parsing, expression

I'm writing a program that needs to build syntax trees from expressions in prefix notation. What resources would you recommend I look into to learn about parsing expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather broad. I'd look into anything dealing with the following:

- [Parsing expression-grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)
- [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus-Naur_form)s, [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)`s
- [Recursive-Descent Parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)
- [Operator-precedence parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser) (basically prefix parser)
- [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) (talks about prefix notation)

Your best bet is to try and understand BNF's and EBNF's. From there you can go on to writing recursive-descent parsers (they can be created easily from your grammars with a few simple rules).

This page [here](http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/1702911:BlogPost:1683) talks about recursive-descent parsing using BNF's.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the stuff already listed, I'd recomment to consider the following:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar